Does setting a value using the indexer count as an "insertion" into an OrderedDictionary?
I'm using the new .NET 9 OrderedDictionary<TKey,TValue> generic class to store things by key and also maintain insertion order, but all the examples I've seen use .Insert() to actually insert new values in a way where the order is guaranteed to be maintained.  I want to insert things using the indexer and have it insert if the key doesn't currently exist, but does this actually count as an insert which is guaranteed to maintain the order in which the keys were set?  I think it does, because the following code does what I want:
OrderedDictionary<string, bool> dict = new();
dict["foo"] = true;
dict["bar"] = false;
dict["baz"] = true;
dict.RemoveAt(1);
dict["boo"] = true;
dict.Insert(1, "xxx", false);
dict["baz"] = false;
string dictValues = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> entry in dict) {
    dictValues += $", {entry.Key}={entry.Value}";
}
dictValues = dictValues[2..]; // foo=True, xxx=False, baz=False, boo=True

However I can't find any documentation saying that this behaviour is guaranteed to stay the same and not just an implementation detail.  Could anyone point me to some?

Yeah, the docs on that type are kind of rubbish, aren't they? They don't even say that Add appends the value

Reading the source I think it's fairly clear that the indexer is supposed to append (there's explicitly-written code to do that, rather than it just being an artifact of some other implementation detail), but I can't find any doc to support that

FYI: OrderedDictionary is very old and exists since .net framework 2.0.

The docs are bad, aren't they?  They don't even link to the sources properly.  You can find the source for the setter here, the logic is to look up the existing key and use its index if found.  If not found, append.

@GoodNightNerdPride - the question is about the new OrderedDictionary<TKey,TValue> from .NET 9

There are two OrderedDictionarys in the same framework?! That's a nice trap to fall into.

@GoodNightNerdPride - there are other examples of generic and non-generic types with the same identifier in the framework. E.g. SortedList and SortedList<TKey,TValue> or IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>.  Typically the namespaces differ, which is true for OrderedDictionary and OrderedDictionary<TKey,TValue> as well.

The documentation is missing lots of important details. There is merely a hint in the Remarks section of the indexer this[TKey] saying

Setting the value of an existing key does not impact its order in the collection.

In fact, the setter of the indexer doesn't simply Add. It looks up the key. If it exists it updates the value, otherwise it adds a new key/value pair.
You can see the implementation in the .NET Source Browser:
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
    get
    {
        if (!TryGetValue(key, out TValue? value))
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFound(key);
        }

        return value;
    }
    set
    {
        ThrowIfNull(key);

        bool modified = TryInsert(index: -1, key, value, InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting, out _);
        Debug.Assert(modified);
    }
}

It calls TryInsert whose implementation is quite complex and hard to understand (therefore I won't insert the code here). However, comments say:

index: The index at which to insert the pair, or -1 to append.

and

If a non-negative index was provided, that is the desired index at which to insert [ ... ]. If negative, we're appending.

In the indexer shown above, TryInsert is called with index = -1, which means "append", but at the same time with InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting, which is a bit contradictory. However, a look at the implementation shows that with InsertionBehavior.OverwriteExisting the index is ignored if the key exists and the value is then updated.
There is also code there that deals with the intricate details of hash tables. Apparently, the private utility method TryInsert, which covers various use cases, has been optimized not for readability but for efficiency.
